# A "clone looking" tomato plant with no fruit

Tags: identification

We've had volunteer cherry tomatoes come up in our yard, but this isn't a cherry tomato.   The plant I am questioning came up next to a bird feeder in a flower bed.  It now is about 21/2 ft. tall and seems to still be growing.  It has leaves that look exactly like a regular tomato plant, but with stickers on the stems.  I was sure it was a tomato as it blossomed with yellow flowers, tho they look a little ruffled (or double) but the size of a real tomato plant flower. However when the blooms fall off, there is no sign of a tomato starting on the stem.  It is erect, no sign that it wants to trail and the stems & branches are sturdy.  I am sorry I cannot send a picture.

Comment: Nightshade, horsenettle..? Got a picture? If you can't mange to post one, try looking at some on the web to see if you can find a similar-looking plant.

Comment: The 'stickers' on the stem would match up nicely with horsenettle

Comment: Was this bird feeder in the bed last year? I'm asking because a number of things grow randomly where seeds fall from my feeders, like sunflowers! It could be a wildflower from a bird food mix. Alternatively, some birds carry seeds and drop them when they find something more interesting at a new feeder. This is just a guess based on my experience and doesn't help your identification question, for which I apologize!

Comment: Litchi tomatoes have thorns, but I doubt you'd find one wild unless you're in areas where it's native.